# How to remove "Visit" and "Search with..." from the Firefox 68 urlbar?

Tags: firefox

How to remove the first address bar item (Visit/Search with...) from Firefox 68+? They've changed the code, so older CSS snippets no longer work.

Firefox 68

Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to userChrome.css hides those elements:

`#urlbar-results .urlbarView-row:first-child{display:none !important}`

My problem is that I still had the XUL `@namespace` line at the top of my rules. That line must be removed now.

Answer (score 0):

In my config your given code removes the "Visit/Search.." element, but a thick white line still appears below the address bar. Adding this: #urlbar-results{display:none !important} solved that problem for me.

Comment: Yeah, but I only wanted to hide that line, and not all URL suggestions (bookmarks/history entries).

Answer (score 0):

You can set this pref to false on the about:config page. No need to change CSS.

browser.urlbar.oneOffSearches = false